# Change disk icon / volume icon using swift

Tags: swift, macos

How to change the icon of a volume (disk) using swift.

I have tried with the following code:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.setIcon(NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Image")),
           forFile:"/Volumes/Macintosh HD",
           options: NSWorkspace.IconCreationOptions.excludeQuickDrawElementsIconCreationOption)
```

The problem is that it is only working for normal folders and files, but not disk/volume icons.